# Connect the other user through remote machine on local machine?

Tags: java, ssh

I wanted to connect a Remote machine using java and have to run some commands from cmd prompt. To do this, I need a confirmation the tool (AutoIt) which i picked is working fine for me. Is there any possible to connect two users in our laptop and connect the other user by remote machine.. so that i can verify and proceed..

Any possibility to write a program to ssh to remote machine and execute some commands?

Comment: consider using jsch using a shell channel

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

> JSch is a pure Java implementation of SSH2.
>
> JSch allows you to connect
> to an sshd server and use port forwarding, X11 forwarding, file
> transfer, etc., and you can integrate its functionality into your own
> Java programs